# how can I convert a text file with numbers seperated by white space to a CSV file with Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, csv, text

Hello i want to pull data from a numeric website and convert it to a csv file. i was first storing the data in a text file then convert it to a csv file.
how do i get this to work ?

```
     <code>
    <while t > 0:
    f = open("testtext.txt", "a")
    url = "http://www.kool.com/en/results"
     newString = newString + " " + data1[start:end]
    print(newString)


    f.write(newString + '\n')
    f.close()
    t =t -1
    x =x - 1
    print("DONE")

  </code>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
string = string.replace(" ", ",")
```

This replaces spaces with commas.